# Segment control white line between segmentAtIndex and dividerImage

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, divider

My question is the following. Actually, I use segment control with images instead of text.
So, for images I write this code:

> [self.segmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DividerImageLeft.png"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
>
> [self.segmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DividerImageRight.png"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
>
> [self.segmentedControl setImage:[­[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment_left.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
> [self.segmentedControl setImage:[­[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment_right.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forSegmentAtIndex:0];

As the result, there is a white line between divider and segments (It is only for iOS 7.0+, because it works fine without divider image on iOS 6.1.3 and lower). How can I remove it?
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s305/sh/cda3f2b3-74e6-4268-9d0d-278be9f9e95f/d4110a56f9fe38311cfbe7001d6f9825

Comment: This problem was solved via adding         
[self.segmentedControl setContentOffset:CGSizeMake(-8, 0) forSegmentAtIndex:1];
For each segmentAtIndex.

Comment: If you have solved your question, then write your answer in answer field and accept it. It'll help others.